# How to join tables so that column values are displayed in rows

Tags: sql, postgresql

[image]

[image]

I have two tables task and task_attribute. I want to join tables in a way that the output is

[image]

Keys in the table are fixed and I would like to make a query which will select values of that keys in one row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems like a basic `join` and aggregation query.  In Postgres, you can use conditional aggregation with `filter`:

```
select t1.name,
       max(t2.value) filter (where key = 'A') as a,
       max(t2.value) filter (where key = 'B') as b
from table1 t1 join
     table2 t2
     on t1.taskid = t2.taskid
group by t1.name;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use joins to do this as a standard pattern

```
select t.name, a.value as A, b.value as B, c.value as C
from task t
left join task_attribute a on t.taskid = a.taskid and a.key = 'A'
left join task_attribute b on t.taskid = b.taskid and b.key = 'B'
left join task_attribute c on t.taskid = c.taskid and c.key = 'C'
```

Note this assumes taskid and key are unique in the task_attribute table.